# Number of repeated results in a series of coin tosses

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

When I execute a series of $n$ coin tosses, with probability of heads being $0.5$, what is the probability distribution for the number of repetitions of heads over the series?

> **Clarification:**$\;$
>
> > Two consecutive heads counts as one repetition. For example:
> >
> > - The $10$-term sequence **TT-HHHH-T-HHH** has $5$ repetitions ($3$ from the block **HHHH**, and $2$ from the block **HHH**).$\\[4pt]$
> >
> >   The $5$-term sequence **H-T-H-TT** has $0$ repetitions.

Equivalently, when I list all possible $n$-term sequences of heads and tails, I get a list of length $2^n$. For a given integer $r$, with $0\le r\le n-1$, how can I calculate how many times this list contains results with $r$ repetitions.

**Edit:**$\;$I think I found the answer, with it being simply a binomial distribution with probability $p^r$, where $r$ is the number of repetitions. This is described on the Wikipedia page

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Conditional_binomials

for the binomial distribution, under "conditional binomial".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85092/discussion-on-question-by-d0d0-number-of-repeated-results-in-a-series-of-coin-to).

Comment: @d0d0: To test the answer you found (conditional binomial), can you show how to use it to compute the probability of a rep count of $4$ in $10$ tosses?

Comment: @quasi: according to my conditional binomial answer, the probability of a head-rep count of 4 in 10 tosses (with a fair coin) is 0.146

Comment: @d0d0: By my calculation, the probability of a rep-count of $4$ in $10$ tosses is
$$\frac{116}{2^{10}}=\frac{29}{256}\approx 0.1132812500$$
which doesn't match your answer.

Comment: @d0d0: Let $f(n,r)$ be the probability of a rep-count of $r$ in $n$ tosses, where $n$ is a positive integer, and $r$ is an integer with $0\le r\le n-1$. Could you edit your question to show the formula you got for $f(n,r)$?

Comment: The binomial probability mass function is

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is a positive integer, and $r$ is a nonnegative integer, let $f(n,r)$ be the number of $n$-term sequences yielding a rep count of $r$.

Here are two different methods for computing $f(n,r)$ . . .

**Method $(1)$:**$\;$Using recursion . . .

Let $g(n,r)$ be the number of $n$-term sequences yielding a rep count of $r$, assuming a prior toss of heads.

Then for $f$, we get
$$
f(n,r)=
\begin{cases}
\text{if}\;r > n-1,\;\text{then}\\[5pt]
\qquad 0\\[5pt]
\text{else if}\;n=1,\;\text{then}\\[5pt]
\qquad 2\\[5pt]
\text{else}\\[5pt]
\qquad g(n-1,r)+f(n-1,r)\\[20pt]
\end{cases}
\;\;\;\;\;
$$
and for $g$, we get
$$
g(n,r)=
\begin{cases}
\text{if}\;r > n,\;\text{then}\\[5pt]
\qquad 0\\[5pt]
\text{else if}\;n=1,\;\text{then}\\[5pt]
\qquad 1\\[5pt]
\text{else if}\;r=0,\;\text{then}\\[5pt]
\qquad f(n-1,r)\\[5pt]
\text{else}\\[5pt]
\qquad g(n-1,r-1)+f(n-1,r)\\
\end{cases}
$$
As a sample, for $n=10$, the above recursion yields the following results . . .
$$
\begin{array}
{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
r&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9\\ 
\hline
f(10,r)&144&235&241&187&116&62&25&11&2&1\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
**Method $(2)$:**$\;$Expressed as a summation . . .

Then for $f$, we get
$$
f(n,r)
=
\sum_{h=r}^{\left\lfloor{\large{\frac{n+r+1}{2}}}\right\rfloor} 
{\small{\binom{h-1}{h-r-1}}}{\small{\binom{n-h+1}{h-r}}}
$$
which yields results matching those obtained from the recursion.